# Identifying the pet with in camera frame

Tags: react-native

We are wondering if we can achieve this using react native. Using react-native-vision-camera with a custom frame where we can identify whether an object is within the frame or has it moved away in the designated frame. As of now we have implemented a frame on top of the camera. But we are unable to identify whether the object is moved away from the frame.

We have tried react-native-vision-camera npm and want alert the user when object moves away from the camera frame.

Comment: Who is "we" in this context?

Comment: _"But we are unable to identify whether the object is moved away from the frame."_ - May I ask what your level of understanding of computer-vision fundamentals is? Are you looking to implement object-detection and classification entirely by yourself _from scratch_ - or are you wanting a premade library that does this in a single call - or would you like to build this functionality from lower-level CV operations?